# How to terminate the process in cider-repl?

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

When running into a deadlock because of an infinite loop, how can I exit from the cider-repl?

When it happens, I have to kill the emacs, or even reboot my computer to kill the cider-repl.  Is there a better way of solving this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The key combination `C-c C-c` will break from a loop at the top level of the cider repl, while leaving emacs and the repl running.

In a regular terminal repl, the equivalent is `C-c`.

Comment: as you can see in the image above , i define a function named random-ints , and define a symbol x using "(def x (rest (random-ints 50)))",so the x is a infinite collection.and I input the "(println x)" ,the emacs paused and I cannot input anything.so I goto the terminal and kill the emacs.

Comment: @RenheHuang I'm not seeing any image

Comment: @ShawnZhang sorry about that.I have a screenshot about what happened,but i cannot upload it.so I describle the "random-ints" as following: (defn random-ints [limit] (lazy-seq (cons (rand-int limit) (random-ints limit)))).and the rest is describled in my last comment.

Comment: If you run `C-c C-c`, emacs will eventually cancel the top level repl command that is looping. This will take a while if it is a tight loop, and even longer if it is producing large amounts of output. But it will eventually stop the code without having to kill emacs.

Comment: Also try `C-c C-b` and `, s X (cider-restart in Spacemacs)`. `C-g` also works in emergencies for all hangs.

Answer (score 1):

When you're editing a file and have *'jacked-into'* a cider repl, by default typing `C-c C-c` runs `cider-eval-defun-at-point`, but typing `C-c C-b` runs `cider-interrupt`, which cancels whatever is being evaluated.